# ASP.NET Embedded CSS Files in MVC / Web Forms Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, webforms

We have a legacy Web Forms application which we've recently converted from a website project to a web application project.

The Web Forms project is the "startup" project of the solution.

There is an MVC project which is a reference to the Web Forms project.

In the MVC project, there are several CSS files that are set as "Embedded Resource". When being debugged locally in visual studio, these files are available via IIS express and the pages are appropriately styled.

When the Web Forms project is published (locally), these CSS files aren't being made available. The console on Google Chrome provides evidence for this, as each file is labelled as 404.

Does anyone know what to do about this?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Ryan

Comment: Could you please provide the URLs of the resources when in IIS express and also in IIS local?

Comment: The IIS Express URLs of CSS files are:

http://localhost:64809/Content/bootstrap.min.css

The IIS URLs of CSS files are:

http://mis/Content/bootstrap.min.css

...etc

Comment: So, these files actually exist in the `Content` folder? If so, you need to include them in the Web forms project so that they are included when published in IIS local.

Comment: Brilliant! That works! Thank you!